# Silverlight 4 Trusted Application - Can I drag widgets outside the window?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a feeling this really isn't possible, but (for example) would it be possible to implement a trusted Silverlight 4 filesystem browser that allows me to drag files from within the Silverlight application to another application on my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows... technically, maybe being able to run your own app when a drag is going outside the area of the app. But super complex and challenging.

You would need a few things:

- Elevated SL4 OOB app
- A COM component on the system, or a native code app embedded in the app that you can execute with parameters about a drag operation, look into isolated storage, etc.

You monitor when a drag starts, and then would need to execute your native code app somehow to realize the drag. Even then, I don't think the new app could pick up on the true drag operation.